# How to separate angular modules in files and require with Browserify?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

I'm using `Angular` for front end use, and I'm trying separate my application per modules.

For organization, I want separate one module per file and all your controllers is a file to, file structure example:

```
- module1 (paste)
    - controllers (paste)
        - controller1.js
        - controller2.js
    - module.js
```

Where `module1.js` require `controller1.js` and `controller2.js`, and main javascript file require all modules file.

For controllers, I'm `module.exports` only content of controller, something like:

```
// controller1.js
module.exports = ["$scope", function(scope) {
  // some code here
}];
```

In my module file, I require it this way:

```
//module1.js
var app = angular.module("module1", []);

app.service("service1", function() {});

app.controller("controller1", require("./controllers/controller1.js");
module.exports = app;
```

Until this point, is allright.

But when I try require `module1.js` to `module2.js` for use `service1`, this is return `service1` is not defined.

```
//module2.js
require('../module1/module.js');

var app = angular.module("module2", ['module1']);
app.controller('controller2-1', ["$scope", "service1", function(scope, service1) {
    // some code
});
```

What is correct way to separate modules per file and require it with `Browserify`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```js
//child module
var angular = require('angular');
var moduleName = 'moduleChild';
var moduleDependencies = [...];

app.module(moduleName, moduleDependencies)
   .controller('foobarctrl', [function(){}]);

module.exports = moduleName;

//parent module
var angular = require('angular');
var moduleChild = require('/path/to/file');
var moduleName = 'moduleChild';
var moduleDependencies = [moduleChild];

app.module(moduleName, moduleDependencies)
   .controller('foobarbazctrl', [function(){}]);

module.exports = moduleName;
```

This way is one of the most cleaner way to use angular with browserify, it is not usefull to exports the module1 object because you don't wan't to reuse it, you just need there name.